# Multiple media items getting created in languages

Tags: media-library

We need to apply the workflow on media items. We are having one problem is that whenever a media item is uploaded in media library, versions are created for all the languages which we have added in language section and the items also show up in workflow for each version language.

How to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Please configure the following setting which by default is false. You need to set it true.

```
<setting name="Media.UploadAsVersionableByDefault" value="false" />
```

If you set it to true, item will be created only in one default language version. This media item will use a versioned template /sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/File template and if it is false, then it will use /Sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File template and create media Item in all those languages which exist under /Sitecore/system/languages.